# Python - list resets as I update it

Tags: python, list, reset

I'm trying to append data to a list but right before I append a new value the list seems to reset. Here's the relevant code:

This is the main module:

```
def update():
    global url
    data.add_price(df.pulldata(url))
```

This is the data module:

```
historical_price = []

def add_price(price):
    historical_price.append(price)
    print(historical_price)
```

I am guessing that the problem is the fact that I am defining historical_price to be empty at the top. This however confuses me, since that whole script is never run. How do I go about fixing this? Hints are appreciated.

Comment: Are `add_price` and `historical_price` part of a class? Where is that located? If that's the case, you probably just want to associate `historical_price` with the instance by using `self.historical_price`. Not sure if that's where your problem is though...

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by reset? Do you mean that it is emptied? If data is a class instance should the add_price function not have a `self` attribute? In my opinion `historical_price` should be `self.historical_price = []` and the function should be modified accordingly.

Comment: Please show more of your code, right now the class definition isn't even there. In particular, how is this code called? We can't reproduce the error just from this.

Comment: How do you know it is reset?

Comment: By *class* do you really mean *module*? So `data` is actually a file `data.py`, not `class data:`?

Comment: Sorry guys I obviously mean module instead of class. I always get them confused. @PeterWood

Comment: It looks like this is not the full code, or at least not the minimum complete example. What is `url`? What is `df.pulldata`? Why is `url`  `global`?

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate the data class, so it's performing `add_price` without an instance to perform it on. You should add `self` as a parameter to `add_price` and you should instantiate your data class something like this.

```
d = data()

def update():
    global url
    d.add_price(df.pulldata(url))
```

You should also make `historical_price` an attribute of the data class, so the data class should look something like this.

```
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.historical_price = []

    def add_price(self, price):
        self.historical_price.append(price)
        print(self.historical_price)
```

Comment: I imagine `data` is a module name, `data.py`.

Comment: OP explicitly states they are confused.

Comment: Sorry guys, it is a module. I always get class and module confused.

Comment: In that case, you should consider creating a data class within the data module and using that (maybe not with those names exactly). Otherwise you'll have to make your `historical_price` variable global I believe.

Comment: @wilbur I've tried global variables but I cannot get it to work correctly. Creating a class would probably fix it, but doesn't it seem ridiculous to create a class for something that cannot be transferred to the real world?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do without seeing more of your code, so I can't really say as to whether or not it's ridiculous. Judging from this one use case though, it doesn't seem so ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `add_price` function is in a different module, this part `historical_price = []` is run everytime you invoke that method.

Invoking a global function executes all global code first, then executes the function.

To fix this, you could:

1. Write a class with that list as an instance variable and instantiate it in your main code.
2. Write that class and make the method static, using the list as a class variable.
3. Define the gobal variable in your main code and hand it to the function as a parameter.

The main code is the top level code that controls the flow of the program by invoking methods and instantiating classes.